# Simple deployment solution without using Windows Store

Tags: deployment, windows-store-apps, windows-store

We have a system which has Windows 8.1 store app and iPad solutions as frontends and a MVC web as the backend.

We have lot of clients and they prefer hosting the web on premise due to sensitivity of the data. (So no cloud hosting)

Each client runs on different versions of the backend and for those we provide according frontend version as well.

Eg: 3.15.5 backend we have 3.15.5 frontend iPad app. (Backend provides a download link to iPad app, it will automatically update the existing app in the iPad)

(We can't make the frontend apps backward compatible due to high maintenance)

But for our Windows 8.1 app also we have relevant versions but we don't know how to deploy it simply.

We can't ask the customer to run powershell scripts either.

We can't use the Windows store because every time we publish the latest version of the app all our backends need to upgrade as well. Which is not possible due to large no of clients we have.

So my question is how do I provide a simple download solution for Windows 8.1 app that can be operate by a non IT personal?

Comment: Try googling about "Microsoft Intune"